# Redirects in PHP website not working properly

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have written htaccess file. I want to redirect https://example.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=1 to https://example.com/fashion.

My htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it is not redirecting to the link I have shown

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this to redirect all request to your index.php and then manage the requests from there usint*HTTP-PATH. **var_dump($_SERVER)** to see the actual request.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

If you want to redirect a specific request, then someone else may help you here later on.

Comment: I have already written this two lines. But still the result is not working. I am using opencart for making this.

Comment: do you have the correct name for your htaccess? it should be ".htaccess" not htaccess?

Comment: Yes I have written .htaccess only. It is reading it if I made any changes

Comment: Maybe because you have two extra underlines in your htaccess for ?_route_= instead of ?route=

Comment: I have tried what u r saying but when I do that the category page is redirected to the main website link.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this. I hope this will help you a lot. And if not work visit https://github.com/aice09/htaccess/blob/master/redirects/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?category/([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```